# SQL Nested Select with faculty members

Tags: sql, ms-access

```html
SELECT FacSSN, FacLastName, FacDept
FROM Faculty
WHERE FacSSN IN
   (SELECT DISTINCT FacSSN FROM Offering 
      WHERE OffTerm = 'WINTER' 
        AND OffYear = 2006 );
```

I have a question which is meant for revision for an exam, This is the question:
List the name (first and last) and department of faculty who are only teaching in winter 
term 2006

However there is a person which has a lecture in winter 2006 and summer 2006, the question does not want to list that person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use EXISTS clause instead of IN:

```
SELECT 
      FacSSN, FacLastName, FacDept
FROM 
      Faculty 
WHERE EXISTS
     (SELECT * FROM Offering 
      WHERE OffTerm='WINTER' AND OffYear=2006 AND FacSSN=Faculty.FacSSN)
      AND NOT EXISTS        
     (SELECT * FROM Offering 
      WHERE (OffTerm<>'WINTER' OR OffYear<>2006) AND FacSSN=Faculty.FacSSN)
```

There is also no need to use DISTINCT in subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `FacSSN` holds the person who is lecturing this should work:

```
SELECT 
    FacSSN, FacLastName, FacDept
FROM 
    Faculty
WHERE 
    FacSSN IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT FacSSN FROM Offering WHERE OffTerm = 'WINTER' AND OffYear = 2006)
    AND FacSSN NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT FacSSN FROM Offering WHERE OffTerm <> 'WINTER' AND OffYear = 2006);
```

Comment: Are you sure that `!=` is a valid SQL operator?

Comment: Yet I have tried both versions of the code and they select blank fields

Comment: @Jackson It should work. Let me clarify: is `FacSSN` holding the person who is lecturing?

Comment: Your answer is code only and thus automatically appears in the "low quality posts" queue.

Comment: @SmartDev This is the data fields for both tables which I just uploaded. http://imgur.com/wnMLY7b,Mq3oish P.s. is it important to note that my FacSSN is a text since one user started with a 0?

Answer (score 0):

I would write the query like that

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.FacSSN, F.FacLastName, F.FacDept
FROM Faculty F
    INNER JOIN Offering Winter ON Winter.FacSSN = F.FacSSN AND Winter.OffYear = 2006 AND Winter.OffTerm = 'WINTER'
    LEFT JOIN Offering Other ON Other.FacSSN = F.FacSSN AND (Other.OffYear <> 2006 OR Other.OffTerm <> 'WINTER')
WHERE Other.FacSSN IS NULL
```